# Joomla JUser return 0

Tags: php, ajax, session, joomla

Hi (sorry for bad English :c)
I have a trouble in my code. There are two versions of site in web - dev and main.
Both use php 5.4 and have one host provider. But in dev site all work well and on main - not.
So about problem
I'm use XMLHttpRequest to send ajax requests to php file, that included in start other file (head of ajax controller). Here source of this (last) file :

```
<?PHP

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../../' );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );


require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

JFactory::getApplication('site')->initialise ();
$user = JFactory::getSession()->get( 'user' );
$___temp_user =& JFactory::getUser();
$user_id = $___temp_user->get('id');
```

but, how i said, on main $___temp_user return 0; (im loggined in)
please, tell me why this happen.

(Joomla 1.5.9)

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../../' );
```

Should not be same for both the sites.

Doubly check the path or do a

```
var_dump(JPATH_BASE); exit;
```

You can also give hardcoded path of your joomla installation like

```
define('JPATH_BASE', '/var/www/joomla' );
```

Comment: Files included successfully, it create user class with NULLs in fields

Comment: What did you get when you did var_dump of JPATH_BASE ?

Comment: 'string(38) "/home/fint18/[>here addr site<]/www/ajax/../"'